# How to make strawberries bear fruits?

Tags: strawberries

I have a hundred potted strawberries and some on plots. I've taken care for more than six months and they haven't borne flowers. They just kept growing some runners, and I have a hard time preparing more pots to grow more strawberries.

Comment: Where are you located? And what kind of strawberries? There are two distinct kinds, June Bearing and Everbearing. Obviously if you are in the Southern Hemisphere, June Bearing would become December Bearing.

Comment: I'm in the Philippines. I don't actually know what kind of strawberries I planted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When planting June bearing strawberries in a northern hemisphere temperate climate you do not expect a crop for one year. If I were to put out new plants in May 2016 I would not expect a crop until June 2017.

Not sure how that would translate to a tropical location like the Philippines.

Answer (score 1):

Try dried carabao or chicken dung as fertilizer. More effective than the usual commercial fertilizers.

Flowers usually shoot out from late November to early February.

Plants are grown in 6-inch diameter/6-inch circular pots due to space limits.  Placed under full sun.

Location: Quezon City Hall area, near Quezon Memorial